# Having an overloaded operator<< compiler cannot find it

Tags: c++, vector, singleton, operator-overloading

I have written a small class `Dice` that imitates the behavior of real dice and templated class `Singleton` that `Dice` can inherit from.  I have written `operator<<` for class `Dice` but somehow compiler is having problems with finding it. I have overloaded `<<` operators for `Dice` , `Sinlgeton<Dice>` and `std::vector<int>` which is returned from some `Dice` methods and it's handy to have it.

I use `Qt creator 2.5` with `gcc 4.7` on ubuntu.

> /home/USER/programming/cpp_yahtzee/main.cpp:12: error: no match for
>   ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<<  >((* &
>   std::cout), ((const char*)"hello")) << (&
>   Singleton::Instance())->Dice::getLastThrow()’

and this is the codes that produces this error :

`std::cout << "hello" << Dice::Instance().getLastThrow();`

**EDIT** 
Yet this outputs what expected with no error at all : 
`std::cout <<  Dice::Instance()`
Maybe that's a problem with my compiler `gcc/g++ 4.7` (tried `gcc/g++ 4.6.3` and the effect is the same) ?

My sinlgeton class

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T& Instance();
    Singleton() {}
private:

    //declare them to prevent copies
    Singleton(Singleton const&);
    void operator=(Singleton const&);

};

template<typename T>
T& Singleton<T>::Instance()
{
    static T _instance;
    return _instance;
}
```

Dice class :

```
    class Dice : public Singleton<Dice>
    {
    private:
        std::vector<int> _lastThrow;
    public:
        Dice();
        std::vector<int> generateThrow();
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dice& dice);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Singleton<Dice>& dice);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int>& vect);

        //accessor method - returning last throw
        const std::vector<int>& getLastThrow();

        //rethrowing {1,4} - dice #1 and #4
        std::vector<int> Rethrow(const std::vector<int>& objects);
    };

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dice& dice)
{
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = dice._lastThrow.begin();  it != dice._lastThrow.end(); ++it) {
        os << *it;
    }
    return os;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Singleton<Dice>& dice)
{
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = dice.Instance().getLastThrow().begin();  it != dice.Instance().getLastThrow().end(); ++it) {
        os << *it;
    }
    return os;

}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int>& vect)
{
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = vect.begin();  it != vect.end(); ++it) {
        os << *it;
    }
    return os;
}

std::vector<int> Dice::generateThrow()
{
    static std::vector<int> v(5);

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();  it != v.end(); ++it) {
        (*it) = rand()%(DICE_MAX)+1;
    }
    _lastThrow = v;
    return v;
}
```

Now I cannot do something like this :

`std::cout << Dice::Instance().generateThrow();`

**EDIT** 
Ilya Lavrenov's method is working although this is not what I want because this requires creating a local variable. I have a problem somewhere with the `Singleton` class.

Comment: The code you posted is fine (except for obvious spelling errors and missing functions). Post a [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Can you show the `main` function, where the error is? Also, you really don't need the functions to be friend of the class. You can use the `getLastThrow()` method instead of accessing the attribute `_lastThrow` directly.

Comment: Yep, this code works just fine.

Comment: @PierreBdR The error is at the line I have mentioned on the bottom of my question `std::cout << Dice::Instane().generateThrow();`. That's all my my function for now.

Comment: That line is definitely not the same one that generated the error message (e.g. where did the string `"hello"` in the error message come from?). -1 and voting to close for refusing to post code that actually exhibits the problem.

Comment: @Patryk as interjay said, post a compilable code that produce the error.

Comment: @interjay I have posted the code that causes the error.

Comment: You have posted code that doesn't cause the error. Until you post code that we can try compiling for ourselves and see the error, this question can't be answered.

Comment: @interjay I have updated the answer with the code that compiles and runs fine but I have no idea why it works like this `cout<<Dice::Instance();` and not like `cout<<Dice::Instance().getLastThrow();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T& Instance();
    Singleton() {}
private:

    //declare them to prevent copies
    Singleton(Singleton const&);
    void operator=(Singleton const&);

};

template<typename T>
T& Singleton<T>::Instance()
{
    static T _instance;
    return _instance;
}

class Dice : public Singleton<Dice>
{
private:
    std::vector<int> _lastThrow;
public:
    Dice()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            _lastThrow.push_back(i);
    }
    std::vector<int> generateThrow();

    //accessor method - returning last throw
    const std::vector<int>& getLastThrow()
    {
        return _lastThrow;
    }

    //rethrowing {1,4} - dice #1 and #4
    std::vector<int> Rethrow(const std::vector<int>& objects);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dice& dice)
{
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = dice.Instance().getLastThrow().begin();  it != dice.Instance().getLastThrow().end(); ++it) {
        os << *it;
    }
    return os;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Singleton<Dice>& dice)
{
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = dice.Instance().getLastThrow().begin();  it != dice.Instance().getLastThrow().end(); ++it) {
        os << *it;
    }
    return os;

}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int>& vect)
{
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = vect.begin();  it != vect.end(); ++it) {
        os << *it;
    }
    return os;
}

std::vector<int> Dice::generateThrow()
{
    static std::vector<int> v(5);

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();  it != v.end(); ++it) {
        (*it) = rand()%(354535)+1;
    }
    _lastThrow = v;
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    Singleton<Dice> a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Some changes of your code and now its compiles well. And operator << also works well

Comment: The OP probably has a good reason to use the singleton rather than a local variable ...

Answer (score 0):

Would it have anything to do with the typo `Dice::Instane` -> `Dice::Instance` ?

Comment: Nope - just edited my question - this is not the problem.

Answer (score -3):

sometimes IDE intrepret  diffrent some 'const' operators for instance eclipse and virtual studio. The jsut remove from  the paramters 'const'

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<int>& vect)
```

I think it is useful, if not please tell me the complier version and IDE you use.

Comment: This is a terrible idea! the `operator<<` should never modify its argument. And with your version, you won't be able to use it on constant/temporary variables.

Comment: Ok than try in eclipse your point and you will see what i ment.